# How to always display ngx-datatable row detail?

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I see in the [documentation about how to toggle displaying a row detail](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/demo/basic/row-detail.component.ts) but I haven't been able to find anywhere how to always display row detail for every row.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe someone is still searching for the solution...

Yes of course, this is possible.
fist make sure that your ngx-datatable instance have a template reference:

```
<ngx-datatable
   #myTable
   class="material"
   [columnMode]="'force'"
   [headerHeight]="50">
```

than in your typeScript code take this reference with ViewChild selector:

```
@ViewChild('myTable') table: any;
```

now you can collapse or expand all the rows of the table within the api of ngx-datatable in your TypeScript code:

```
this.table.rowDetail.collapseAllRows();
this.table.rowDetail.expandAllRows();
```

or wherever you want in the template:

```
(click)="table.rowDetail.collapseAllRows()"
(click)="table.rowDetail.expandAllRows()"
```

Hope this is helpful.